# template preprocess override not respected

Tags: views, theming

I'm using Drupal 7.

I have a template preprocess function overridden in my `template.php` as

It does not alter the output as desired.

When I comment out (or delete) the original preprocessor (`template_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars)`)
in the contrib module's `theme.inc`, the overridden preprocess function then takes effect as it should.

What do I have to do to get my preprocess to work without having to hack a contributed module?

Here is the offending code:

```
function ncmr_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars){
  $form = $vars['form'];

  if ($form['ncmr_days_only']) {
    $form['ncmr_days_only']['value']['day']['#options'] = array(
      '' => 'Select Day',
      '5' => 'April 5',
      '6' => 'April 6',
      '7' => 'April 7',
    );

    $form['ncmr_days_only']['value']['day']['#printed'] = FALSE;
    $form['ncmr_days_only']['value']['month']['#value'] = 4;
    $form['ncmr_days_only']['value']['month']['#printed'] = FALSE;
    $form['ncmr_days_only']['value']['year']['#value'] = 2013;
    $form['ncmr_days_only']['value']['year']['#printed'] = FALSE;

    $vars['widgets_ncmr']['filter-field_session_date_value']->widget = drupal_render($form['ncmr_days_only']['value']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code?

Comment: have you tried using mythemename_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars)

Comment: Yes I am, see above.

Comment: This just seems very wrong. It's a theme function for all filter forms but your using it for a specific form.

Comment: If your going to do this you should probably try and incorporate your code with the existing code i.e. copy all the code from core then add yours to it on your theme override.

Comment: I just started off doing that :)

Comment: ahhhhh, ok now that i have the whole function copied in verbatim with 'mythemename' overwriting 'template' in the function name being the only change.  And now all the filters on the page have just dissapeared.

Comment: Having looked at it now, see answer below, should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars, $hook)
{
        if ($vars['form']['#id'] == 'FORM_ID')
        {
              // blah blah
        }
}
```

This way you shouldnt override the core stuff, thus not affecting your code either.